# AudioKit empty file using renderToFile with AKSequencer

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm trying to use AudioKit.renderToFile() to export short MIDI passages to audio (m4a):

```
// renderSequencer is an instance of AKSequencer
self.renderSequencer.loadMIDIFile(fromURL: midiURL)
Conductor.sharedInstance.setInstrument(renderItem.soundID, forOfflineRender: true)
// we only have one track with note content
for track in self.renderSequencer.tracks {
    if track.isNotEmpty {
        track.setMIDIOutput(Conductor.sharedInstance.midiIn)
    }
}
let audioCacheDir = self.module.stateManager.audioCacheDirectory
// strip name off midi file
let midiFileName = String(midiURL.lastPathComponent.split(separator: ".")[0])
audioFileName = midiFileName
audioFileURL = audioCacheDir.appendingPathComponent("\(midiFileName).m4a")
if let audioFileURL = audioFileURL {
    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
   ]
   let audioFile: AVAudioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: audioFileURL, settings: settings)
   // get time in seconds of audio file (with 4-beat tail)
   var duration: Float64 = 0.0
   MusicSequenceGetSecondsForBeats(seq, (16.0 + 4), &duration)
   // render sequence
   do { try AudioKit.renderToFile(audioFile, duration: duration) {
       self.renderSequencer.setRate(60.0)
       self.renderSequencer.play()
       }
   } catch { print("Error performing offline file render!") }
}
```

This does produce an audio file of the expected duration, but it is silent. I've also tried logging from my MIDI output and can see that the events "played" from inside the preload closure are actually being sent/handled.

Mostly, I suppose, I'm curious to know whether this is actually *expected* to work. I've seen a couple of posts suggesting that renderToFile from MIDI is not supported (while others have suggested they have it working).

I did, btw, also post an issue on the audiokit GitHub.

Comment: Okay, found a problem elsewhere that solved the silence problem, but now it's rendering a kind of pitched noise! Ha... Really curious whether this is actually supposed to work with MIDI. (I can see why it wouldn't, btw.)